# Do we have any control over badges?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges

I started thinking about what kinds of behavior we might want to encourage that are different from other stackexchanges, and how changing the badges might achieve that, but then I realized I don't know if we have control over that.

Comment: I hope so - of all the Stack Exchange sites, an RPG QA site should have fun "advancement" :D

Comment: That would be fantastic, but I am not very optimistic, for the following reason: I think it would turn out to be too demanding to implement from the software point of view. The badge system is most likely programmed on-the-spot with a set of scripts that scans the db periodically and assign badges accordingly. With so many communities eventually asking for customized badges, it would put an excessive demand for tailor-made scripts querying the database. However, let's see what the future brings forward...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the type of question to bring to meta.stackoverflow - which serves as a QA for all the StEx sites.

[Is the list of badges standard?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61835/is-the-list-of-bagdes-standard)